# Self-Signed SSL Certificate Changes Upon Retrieval

Tags: python, ssl, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple flask HTTPS server running using a self-signed certificate on a google compute instance. Here is the code for the server:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

with open("test_certificate.pem",'r') as inputFile:
    print(inputFile.read())

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context=("test_certificate.pem", "test_key.pem"), 
        debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=443)
```

When I start the server I receive the following output:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I was having issues sending HTTPS requests (I was receiving SSL "bad handshake" errors), so I executed the following code to see what the certificate was that was being returned:

```
import ssl 

serverSSL = ssl.get_server_certificate(('20.42.490.329',443))
print(serverSSL)
with open(VERIFY_PATH, 'w') as outputFile:
    outputFile.write(serverSSL)
```

This code outputs the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Why do these certificates not match? I am assuming this is why I am getting the bad handshake error. Any suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: Hello, could you describe a bit your achitecture please,  is the flask directly serving, or is it behind an engine X. 
Are you sure of the IP of the node?

Thank you in advance, have a lovely day.

Comment: Hi Guillauma, it's just a regular compute-engine instance that is directly serving. I was able to communicate via regular HTTP without issue so I don't think it is an issue with the IP. Thanks

Comment: They are different certificates. One is issued by: Issuer: 35.231.110.149, A
Serial Number: 15522555520519877927 (0xd76b3200feddb527). The second by: Issuer: UPHS_FIREWALL, UPHS Serial Number: 4fc3b7175ad3650827. The rest of the certificate is the same. Does UPHS mean something to you?

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful! Yeah, UPHS is the corporate network that I am within. I just tried sending the https request from my home network and that works without issue. Maybe this means that the firewall is intercepting and for some reason modifying the certificate. I just tried saving the modified certificate and using that as the "verify" argument in a requests.get call but still get a bad handshake error. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are using invalid certificates, and the reason why the file changes every time is that you are corrupting it.

This is what I use to get a TRUSTED certificate that most browsers can use: `https://certbot.eff.org/instructions`. Comment and tell me if this works for you.

Tho, if you really want to test this, just use

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
```